# Sails 1.0, How to call customToJSON from an Action2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

Well, I have a user model that needs to implement customToJSON and make the removal of the password for the object to be returned json.
When I put the "responseType" in "exits" as "json" everything happens fine, and the password is taken out of the response. However, the responseType: "json" will be deprecated according to the message in the terminal that sends the responseType empty, however the customToJSON is not called. Can anyone help me understand this?

this is the model code:

```
[...]

    attributes: {

    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
    },

    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: 'string',
        minLength: 6,
        required: true,
    },
},

customToJSON: function() {
    return _.omit(this, ['password']); 
},
[...]
```

this is the action code:

```
module.exports = {

friedlyName: 'Users List',

description: 'User list -> all users',

exits: {
    success: {

    }

},

fn: async (inputs, exits) => {

    var users = await User.find();

    return exits.success(users);

}

}
```

this is the message if you put the "responseType: 'json'":

> The `json` response type will be deprecated in an upcoming release.  Please use `` (standard) instead (i.e. remove `responseType` from the `success` exit.)

Answer (score 1):

I defined custom responses inside api/responses folder.

So, for example... for 200 OK response create api/responses/ok.js

and then inside action2 controller method add this to exits:

```
exits: {
    success: {
        description: 'Returns ok response from api/responses/ok.js',
        responseType: 'ok'
    }
}, ...
```

Example of my simple api/responses/ok.js

```
module.exports = function ok(data) {
    return this.res.status(200).json(data);
};
```

You can create responses for each status/exit you need and later on it's easy to maintain exits... I have responses for: badRequest, serverError, forbidden, notFound and unauthorized

Comment: I liked the solution. but from what I understand this seems to be a bug still unresolved, since the framework should provide this natively. you can see this in
https://trello.com/c/5SkpUlhI/402-make-customtojson-work-with-actions2
that represents the trello of the official team of sails js -> v1

Comment: Yep, you are right... But still, I like this better... Code is more maintanable then :)